# Magento 2 Datepicker in checkout default is a disabled date

Tags: magento2, javascript, datepicker

We recently created a system that allows a maximum amount of orders on specific days, and if that max has been reached the date picker greys out the date, this goes all as expected however currently the default date the date picker selects IS a blocked date. How can I make the default date change to the next available date slot?

`datepicker.phtml`:

```
<input class="picking-date-picker" type="text"
                       default="<?= $block->getFirstExpectedPickingDate(); ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->getFirstExpectedPickingDate(); ?>" name="first_shipping_date" autocomplete="off"
                       data-mage-init='{"pickingDatePicker": {
                       "backendFormat": "<?= $block->getBackendFormat(); ?>",
                       "blockedDates": "<?= preg_replace('/\\r\n/',',',$block->getDatesBlocked()); ?>",
                       "blockedDays": "<?= $block->getBlockedDays(); ?>",
                       "frontendFormat": "<?= $block->getFrontendFormat(); ?>",
                       "minDays": "<?= $block->getDaysUntilMinDate(); ?>",
                       "maxDays": "<?= $block->getDaysUntilMaxDate(); ?>"}}'
                />
```

`shipping-date.js`

```
initialize: function() {
    this._super();

    const shippingDate = new dateModel({
        code: 'shipping-date',
        momentFormat: utils.convertToMomentFormat(this.pickerDefaultDateFormat),
        daysOffset: ko.observable(0),
        value: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        default: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        calculatedDate: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        baseDate: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        datesBlocked: ko.observable(this.datesBlocked),
        daysBlocked: this.daysBlocked,
        maxDate: this.options.maxDate
    });

    this.value(shippingDate.value());

    this.value.subscribe(function (value) {
        shippingDate.value(value);
    }, this);
}
```

Image:

[image]

I hope I've included enough code to support my request, if you need anything else from me please do let me know as I've tried to keep it as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through the entire code with my colleague, we discovered that the current `blockedDates` array was overwritten when entering the default value. Still, when it generates the cells, the array is correct. I've removed the overwriting query, and now it works as expected. Thank you for trying to assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `getFirstExpectedPickingDate` function return the date you want to be selected by default? if so - you need to add a `defaultDate` property to the datepicker (using the right format) and it will select the given date by default.

Should look something like this:

```
<input class="picking-date-picker" type="text"
                   default="<?= $block->getFirstExpectedPickingDate(); ?>"
                   value="<?= $block->getFirstExpectedPickingDate(); ?>" name="first_shipping_date" autocomplete="off"
                   data-mage-init='{"pickingDatePicker": {
                   "backendFormat": "<?= $block->getBackendFormat(); ?>",
                   "blockedDates": "<?= preg_replace('/\\r\n/',',',$block->getDatesBlocked()); ?>",
                   "blockedDays": "<?= $block->getBlockedDays(); ?>",
                   "frontendFormat": "<?= $block->getFrontendFormat(); ?>",
                   "minDays": "<?= $block->getDaysUntilMinDate(); ?>",
                   "maxDays": "<?= $block->getDaysUntilMaxDate(); ?>",
                   "defaultDate": "<?= $block->getFirstExpectedPickingDate(); ?>"}}'
            />
```

In your JS:

```
    initialize: function() {
    this._super();

    const shippingDate = new dateModel({
        code: 'shipping-date',
        momentFormat: utils.convertToMomentFormat(this.pickerDefaultDateFormat),
        daysOffset: ko.observable(0),
        value: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        default: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        calculatedDate: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        baseDate: ko.observable(this.firstAvailableDate),
        datesBlocked: ko.observable(this.datesBlocked),
        daysBlocked: this.daysBlocked,
        maxDate: this.options.maxDate,
        defaultDate: this.options.defaultDate
    });

    this.value(shippingDate.value());

    this.value.subscribe(function (value) {
        shippingDate.value(value);
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: This does not solve my issue. But my colleague and I found the issue yesterday